# Detecting HTTP 302 during image load with JS

Tags: javascript, dom, webkit, dom-events, mobile-safari

Is it possible to detect an `HTTP 302` (Moved) response during an image load from JavaScript?

We're using a simple DART ad banner image that does a request-redirect to show the actual creative. The `src` of the image points to the DART server, but if you inspect the request-response communication, you can see the redirect happening:

```
curl -LI "http://ad.doubleclick.net/ad/mycompany.com/main;sz=320x50;ord=9524078512356?"
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://s0.2mdn.net/viewad/12345678/actual_creative.jpg
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 6811
```

In the end, I want to be able to detect the string `actual_creative.jpg`. This only needs to work in Mobile Safari, so I'm hoping there is an event listener I can use to monitor the load at a very low level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get the redirect location url using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @stewe. I wanted to wait a while longer before accepting your answer. I was really hoping there was a different answer. I dug into the webkit api and I agree that there probably no way to do this even with recent webkit extensions.